# Fill up an Arrray from a mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

From my mysql-query I get this array

```
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [time] =>  00:00:00
          [sales] => 55.99
          [orders] => 1
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [time] =>  06:00:00
          [sales] => 46.37
          [orders] => 1
      )

  [2] => Array
      (
          [time] =>  08:00:00
          [sales] => 246.56
          [orders] => 4
      )

  [3] => Array
      (
          [time] =>  10:00:00
          [sales] => 78.66
          [orders] => 1
      )

)
```

Is it possible to fill up the array with the missing time values (e.g. 02:00:00, 04:00:00)
so I would have a complete array with 2 hour time interval.

Comment: It is possible. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, if its possible which array function could I use?

Comment: loop through your array and check if there is a 2 hour difference with the next item in the array. if not, create that item.

Comment: @Ronny Linsener: do you seriously expect to see `fillMyArrayWith2HoursGapsPlease` built in function?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to teach a man to fish, but since this is fairly specific, whatever.

Keep in mind that this answer is *not* copy/paste friendly, as I didn't do all the work for you. There's still a ton of checks you'd need to implement to prevent notices from being thrown left and right with the slightest deviation from the expected data.

Also, here's a 3v4l of the below code; http://3v4l.org/RrNKA

Your data, I assume:

```
$rows = [
    [
        'time'   => '00:00:00',
        'sales'  => 55.99,
        'orders' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'time'   => '06:00:00',
        'sales'  => 46.37,
        'orders' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'time'   => '08:00:00',
        'sales'  => 246.56,
        'orders' => 4,
    ],
    [
        'time'   => '10:00:00',
        'sales'  => 78.66,
        'orders' => 1,
    ]
];
```

Then you'd want to:

```
// isolate the times
$times = array_map(function ($row) {
    return $row['time'];
}, $rows);

// create a list of similarly formatted times from 00:00:00 - 22:00:00
$allTimes = array_map(function ($hour) {
    return sprintf('%02d:00:00', $hour);
}, range(0, 22, 2));

// compute the difference
$notTimes = array_diff($allTimes, $times);

// add the notTimes to the original rowset with default values
foreach ($notTimes as $notTime)
{
    $rows[] = [
        'time'   => $notTime,
        'sales'  => 0,
        'orders' => 0,
    ];
}

// sort, because why not
usort($rows, function ($rowOne, $rowTwo) {
    return ((int) $rowOne['time']) > ((int) $rowTwo['time']); // refer to note
});

// dump
var_dump($rows);
```

Which, when dumped yields something like:

```
.
.
.
[2] =>
array(3) {
  'time' =>
  string(8) "08:00:00"
  'sales' =>
  double(246.56)
  'orders' =>
  int(4)
}
[3] =>
array(3) {
  'time' =>
  string(8) "10:00:00"
  'sales' =>
  double(78.66)
  'orders' =>
  int(1)
}
[4] =>
array(3) {
  'time' =>
  string(8) "02:00:00"
  'sales' =>
  int(0)
  'orders' =>
  int(0)
}
.
.
.
```

<sub>**Note** -- Don't sort it this way. This approach, while it works, leverages an "odd" behavior in PHP where casting a `string` to an `int` will "chop" characters that cannot be parsed. Another example of this would be `(int) "123abc"` which would yield `int(123)`. So, in my case `(int) '12:00:00'` simply yields `int(12)`, which works for the sort in this example.</sub>

Comment: If you'd want to account for order you'd just `usort` it into place or would you go with something else? Love the KISS, going one step at a time... I still tend to overcomplicate.

Comment: @FernandoSilva That's correct; I left that as an exercise for the OP ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution, but given what I understood here goes:

```
//your result array
$resultArray = array();
//desired times
$times = array( 
    '00:00:00', 
    '02:00:00', 
    '04:00:00', 
    '06:00:00', 
    '10:00:00', 
    '12:00:00', 
    '14:00:00', 
    '16:00:00', 
    '18:00:00', 
    '20:00:00', 
    '22:00:00' 
);
//new array with desired order and values
$newResult = array();
//loop through times
foreach ($times as $v) {
    $match;
    $innerKey;
    //then run through results to check them against the desired times
    foreach ($resultArray as $key=>$value) {
        //verify if the value aleady exists within the resultArray
        $innerKey = $key;
        if ($resultArray[$key]['time_purchased'] == $v) {
            $match = true;
            //stop the foreach if you find a match
            return;
        } else {
            $match = false;
        }
    }
    //either use the result value or an empty array with the time
    if ($match){
        array_push($newResult, $resultArray[$innerKey]);
    } else {
        $empty = array( 
            'time'=>$v,
            'sales'=>0,
            'orders'=>0
        );
        array_push($newResult, $empty);
    }
}
```

**Edited**
Broke up the logic so it wouldn't repeat the assignments in the inner loop.

Comment: I dont't know why but now the array is looped 44 times. I think this is 11 times multiply with the 4 indexes of the original array

Comment: Inspired by your example I solved it with a very short code `foreach ($times as $time) {
  if ($sales['RESULT'][$time]['time_purchased'] == $time) {
    $new[$time] = $sales['RESULT'][$time];
  } else {
    $new[$time] = array(
      'time_purchased' => $time,
      'sales_today'    => '0',
      'orders_today'   => '0',
    );
  }
  $orders_today_array[] = $sales['RESULT'][$time]['orders_today'] ? $sales['RESULT'][$time]['orders_today'] : 0;
  $sales_today_array[]  = $sales['RESULT'][$time]['sales_today'] ? $sales['RESULT'][$time]['sales_today'] : 0;
}
`